# Gtk.Image hangs on load

Tags: c#, gtk#

I am relatively new to GtkSharp and I am looking to use it in a windows application and I am just trying to perform a very simple operation of reading a image (tif image specifically) from the file system and displaying it to screen.  I have tried many permutations of this but one would imagine that the following code snippet would work but when I execute it hangs indefinitely.

```
GtkImage myImage = new Gtk.Image(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
```

I also tried to read from a lower level object, namely the Gdk.Pixbuf object but it is showing the same behavior.

```
Gdk.Pixbuf myBuffer = new Gdk.Pixbuf(path);
```

I am not wed to this mindset so any advice would be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot speak to this specifically, what seems to have happened is that I went home for the night and suspended my computer.  When I came into work this morning and resumed my computer it seems to be working exactly as expected.  I can only assume that the "suspend/resume" is equivalent to a reboot which has forced a correct reference to the base Gtk libraries.  But this is only a guess.  I miss linux :(